# Cannot copy file from a remote machine using shutil

Tags: python, centos, samba, shared-directory, shutil

I need to copy a file from a remote machine.

The code is something like this

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/home/Shares Folder/file.txt','/home/file.txt')
```

the location of the file is a shared folder but everytime I run this it gives me this error

> File "", line 1, in ?
>
> File "usr/lib/python2.4/shutil.py", line 47, in copyfile
>
> frsc =  open (src,'rb')
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory :
>   '//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/home/Shares Folder/file.txt'

Please take note that I'm running this script in my current machine and the the file that I want to copy is in the remote machine. I am not sure if this detail's relevant, I'm saying anyway.

Im 100% sure that the file is there so I was wondering why it's giving me such error message.

Im using CentOS and python 2.4.3

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutil` doesn't support remote file copies. It's for local copies only.
If both of your machines are UNIX-based, you can try and employ some modules for a transport that you have available (`SSH/SFTP`, `rsync`, whanot)

Comment: I posted a question before here in stackoverflow regarding the matter and one of the methods which was suggested was shutil. and it is also stated in this forum that he is using shutil when copying files from a remote machine http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/copy-file-over-LAN-td1366958.html . The problem with SSH is that it is prompting for password which is kind of hard for me to automate.

Answer (score 1):

You've also tagged with samba and shared-folders - if you're trying to copy via samba, you might want to look into pysmbc or a similar python samba library.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysmbc/ even has an example of opening and reading a file over samba - it's a short step to writing the contents out locally.