# Python - transfer files in the same network using shutil

Tags: python, shutil

I'm moving a .txt file between two servers (Ubuntu and Windows) in the same network.
The following code doesn't show any errors but it doesn't work:

```
def transfer_files_task():

    source_path = r"/root/airflow/testdoc"
    dest_path = f"192.168.xxx.xx\Doc-Share\Logger Output"
    filename = r"/test.txt"
    filenamew = f"\test.txt"
    shutil.copyfile(source_path + filename, dest_path + filenamew)
```

Comment: why do you have `f` in front of your strings in lines 4 and 6?

Comment: it was just a test, I tried with "r" initially but i got this error: "No such file or directory: '/root/airflow/testdoc\test.txt'"

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```py
import os, ntpath, posixpath

def transfer_files_task(): 
     source_file = posixpath.join("/", "root", "airflow", "testdoc", "test.txt") 
     dest_file = ntpath.join("192.168.xxx.xx", "Doc-Share", "Logger Output", "test.txt")
     assert os.path.exists(source_file), f"{source_file} does not exists"
     shutil.copyfile(source_file, dest_file)
```

A small explanation: leave python format your paths, it will save you from many errors. If you do not do that, you have to know how strings work, what characters should be escaped, how to format a path on linux and windows, etc.

Also, a side note about the use of `r` and `f` prefix for strings:

- r stands for raw and it roughly means that you don't have to escape special characters like the backspace. Consequently, `r"\tab" == "\\tab"` and `print(r"\tab")` gives `\tab` while `print("\tab")` gives     `ab`
- f stands for format and is the new way of formatting strings in py36+. It is used as follows:

```py
name="john"
print(f"hello {name}")
# hello john
```

Finally, you might want to check this post: [Cannot copy file from a remote machine using shutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060455/cannot-copy-file-from-a-remote-machine-using-shutil)

Comment: Great solution, thank you. The only issue now is I can't reach the machine because the npath.join doesn't allow double "\" before the IP address: \192.168.xx.xx\Doc-Share\Logger Output\test.txt

Comment: I'm trying with normpath, I'll let you know

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't allow? This works: `ntpath.join("\\\\", "192.168.xxx.xx", "Doc-Share", "Logger Output")` --> see the part about escaping strings...

Comment: BTW, this works too obviously: `ntpath.join(r"\\", "192.168.xxx.xx", "Doc-Share", "Logger Output")`

Comment: I agree with you it should work, but it doesn't again: " No such file or directory: '\\192.168.xxx.xx\\Doc-Share\\Logger Output\\test.txt'"

Comment: Well the file is not found... it's another issue isn't it? Try removing the "test.txt" at the end of the path and if this does not work, you can still have a look to the last link that I included in my answer